# I am having problems reading this SAMLResponse into a SecurityToken object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

I am running a [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider.html) SSO login page, which, when I successfully authenticate myself, does a POST with a SAMLResponse string that contains a base-64 encoded SAML response to my .NET MVC application. I am trying to parse this into a [SecurityToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytoken(v=vs.110).aspx) object, if possible:

```
var tokenString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedSamlToken));
var token = System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(tokenString)));
```

The value of `token` is always null, so it is not parsing it correctly, but why is that?

In the XML of the token, I see among other XML tags and data, the following response tag:

```
<saml2p:Response Destination="https://blah.local/" ID="_be8cc118c528ba0407446b8cc2dca019" InResponseTo="ID-302e3473-f063-43b0-b8e4-b8f47fbbe350" IssueInstant="2015-12-29T16:19:35.603Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://shibboleth.blah.local/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

I was under the impression that the built-in SecurityTokenHandlers could read this type of response. Is that not the case? It is not very clear, as [there was an extension for WIF awhile ago to allow SP-initiated SSO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx), but was not licenseable for production use as far as I understand; although, the link to download it is now dead (much like all of Microsoft's development portal links when you really need something are). My main understanding is that this differs from SAML 2.0 security tokens in that this is SAML-P 2.0, where P stands for "Protocol", and that WIF still does not fully support the SAML 2.0 protocol after all these many years, but does support SAML 2.0 tokens. What is the case? Maybe someone cares to elaborate? **Update: Indeed, as others have commented, SAML-P is still not supported in WIF, even after all of these years.**

My default `SecurityTokenHandlers` collection includes the following different handlers, none of which seem to want to handle this response:

```
SamlSecurityTokenHandler
Saml2SecurityTokenHandler
WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler
X509SecurityTokenHandler
KerberosSecurityTokenHandler
RsaSecurityTokenHandler
SessionSecurityTokenHandler
EncryptedSecurityTokenHandler
```

How can I get a SecurityToken out of this SAMLResponse?

Comment: You are correct. WIF still does support SAML2p. There are implementations out there that do support it, i.e. ADFS or Azure AD support SAML2p as IDP. You could try [Kentor Authentication Services](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices)

Comment: It is so strange that they never integrated it into WIF. Its been one of the most requested features, so hearing this completely baffles me.

Comment: @pepo It wasn't so bad in the end, once you figure out a way to deserialize the assertion properly. The big problem was finding that trick.

Comment: glad to hear (read) that :)

Comment: @pepo Me too :) Nice when things work out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution. Once I grab the SAMLResponse as a string, I can deserialize it, but the method of deserializing is very meticulous because encodings are a surefire way to cause the Saml2SecurityToken constructor to fail when building the token (its a badass for sure).

The idea is simple, grab the `saml2:Assertion` tag from within the XML as an element and use it to build a `SecurityToken`; its tested and works in my situation, so hopefully it may help others:

```
var samlToken = (SecurityToken)null;
var form = await Request.ReadFormAsync(); // I am using IOwinRequest here, but if you are using something else you can probably fetch this parameter from somewhere within HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]; or elsewhere.
if (form.Count() > 0)
{
    var samlResponses = form.GetValues("SAMLResponse");
    if (samlResponses != null && samlResponses.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var samlResponse in samlResponses)
        {
            try
            {
                var decodedSamlResponse = Convert.FromBase64String(samlResponse);
                var reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(decodedSamlResponse));
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlElement));
                var samlResponseElement = (XmlElement)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(samlResponseElement.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
                manager.AddNamespace("saml2", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
                var assertion = (XmlElement)samlResponseElement.SelectSingleNode("//saml2:Assertion", manager);
                samlToken = (Saml2SecurityToken)Options.SecurityTokenHandlers.ReadToken(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(assertion.OuterXml)));
                break;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```